# C# Reloading form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, reload

When user changes background color for example, the Settings.settings file is modified. And it works.

But the application doesn't change it's background color after user clicks OK.
It works only when I close and build the application again.

How can I reload my form or user control on button click? (Tried with .Refresh(), but it doesn't work)

```
    private void refreshSettings()
    {
        this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.bgdColor;
        this.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.fontType;
        this.ForeColor = Properties.Settings.Default.fontColor;
    }

    private void Settings_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        refreshSettings();
        bgdColorLBL.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.bgdColor;
        fontColorLBL.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.fontColor;
        fontTypeLBL.Font = Properties.Settings.Default.fontType;
        fontTypeLBL.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.fontType.Name;
    }

    private void okBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LeagueUC lg = new LeagueUC();
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void bgdColorLBL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog dlg = new ColorDialog();
        dlg.Color = Properties.Settings.Default.bgdColor;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.bgdColor = dlg.Color;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
            bgdColorLBL.BackColor = dlg.Color;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us some code. Maybe it is only the implementation that reads settings and applies the color on form load that actually works.

Comment: if you need to repaint have you tried `this.Invalidate()`?

Comment: Try calling InitializeComponent()

Comment: Show some code, because there are too many unknowns. Plus "`It works only when I close and build the application again`" - what does `build` mean? Recompilation?

Comment: @mortb I added some code. Brad & atbyrd it doesn't work.  aleksey.berezan yes, recompilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run whatever code you have that sets the control's properties at start up from the settings file.

e.g.

```
    private void bgdColorLBL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    ColorDialog dlg = new ColorDialog(); 
    dlg.Color = Properties.Settings.Default.bgdColor; 

    if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    { 
        Properties.Settings.Default.bgdColor = dlg.Color; 
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); 

        Settings_Load(null, null);
    } 
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by start up?

Comment: See edit above.  I would probably then look to refactor this so you don't have to call it with the (null, null) parameters.

Comment: okay it looks like it works, but I can't call it on another form, because it doesn't exist there. Any idea why?

Comment: Settings_Load is a private method.  If you want to call it from elswhere you need to make it public.

Comment: Oh my, I tought it was some implemented function. Okay, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the button click event, just load the backcolor from your settings file.  Something like:

```
this.BackColor = Properties.Settings.Default.Color;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create [binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx) for it. With a little tricks the binding can even allow the immediate interface language switching.

Comment: @DinoVelić I'm afraid I do not.

Answer (score 0):

try this, this changes background color of form in color that you chose from ColorDialog:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ColorDialog dlg = new ColorDialog();

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(dlg.Color.Name);
        }
    }
```